# Recursive subtraction of two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi is wrote an SQL to give me the rest of what left in invoice payment 
REST = (Invoice Total - Payment)

What i have:

```
Invoice_ID|Invoice Total   | Payment   | REST     
----------|----------------|-----------|---------
01        |93              | 10        | 69     
01        |93              | 9         | 69         
01        |93              | 5         | 69
```

This what i got, it's correct but what i really want is recursive REST

```
Invoice_ID|Invoice Total   | Payment   | REST     
----------|----------------|-----------|---------
01        |93              | 10        | 83     
01        |93              | 9         | 74         
01        |93              | 5         | 69
```

Comment: and does `SUM(invoice_total) - SUM(payment)` with appropriate group by help you?

Comment: @dubes (invoice_total) - SUM(payment) over() it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below. Do running total on Payment column and subtract that value with your invoice value.

```
SELECT Invoice_ID,InvoiceTotal   ,Payment,
       InvoiceTotal- Sum(payment)
                   OVER (
                     partition BY Invoice_ID
                     ORDER BY rno) rest
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY Invoice_ID
                   ORDER BY Invoice_ID) rno
        FROM   table_name)a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Invoice_ID INT,InvoiceTotal 
INT,Payment INT,REST INT)
INSERT INTO #Table(Invoice_ID ,InvoiceTotal ,Payment ,REST)
SELECT 01,93,10,69 UNION ALL     
SELECT 01,93,9,69   UNION ALL       
SELECT 01,93,5,69 

;WITH CTE (_Id ,_InvoiceID ,_InvoiceTotal ,_Payment ,_REST )AS
(
 SELECT Id ,Invoice_ID ,InvoiceTotal ,Payment ,(InvoiceTotal - Payment)
 FROM #Table WHERE Id = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Id ,Invoice_ID ,InvoiceTotal ,Payment ,_REST - Payment
 FROM #Table
 JOIN CTE ON CTE._InvoiceID = #Table.Invoice_ID 
 WHERE  _Id = Id - 1 
 )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: This is a question with oracle tag. Your answer seems like sql server.

Comment: SQL also tagged

Comment: @Mansoor SQL != SQL Server. SQL stands for "Structured Query Language" whereas SQL Server is a relational database management system (RDBMS) developed by Microsoft.